# Return value or null when TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined

When selecting an element from an array how can I return a value when the index doesn't exist.

For example:

```
var series = [{data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},
          {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []},{data: []}, {data: []},
          {data: [10]},{data: []},{data: []},{data: []},{data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}]

var x = series[44].data || null;

console.log(x)
```

This still throws an error. Am I using the `|| null` in the wrong way?

Comment: Just do a simple `if` to check if you have any item. If you REALLY need to have it even shorter, then use a `&&` or `||` as a guard.

Comment: @VLAZ as I wrote above that still returns the same error. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: The error says that `series[i]` is `undefined`, hence it can't get `data` out of it. Having `series[i].data || null` still means that the first part throws an error. With a `||` you'd do something like `(series[i] || {}).data` with `&&` it will be a more idiomatic `series[i] && series[i].data`. But still - a simple `if` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the variable "series" at each iteration? You can create it only one time. Why are you looping on `n` and using the value to access another array? It can be inconsistent, if the length of `n` is greater than the length of `series` you can get the error that you reported.

Maybe you meant something like this:

```js
var series = [{data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []},{data: []}, {data: []},{data: [10]},{data: []},{data: []},{data: []},{data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}];

series.forEach(serie => console.log(serie.data));
```

This is a basic programming concept, maybe you can go further studying these concepts :)

---

### Edit

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, maybe you meant something like this:

```
var x = series[i] || series[i].data
console.log(x)
```

Does it fix your problem?

Comment: As I've mentioned above this is part of a larger project, so there are several other lines of code below. I don't know if the downvote came from you but it's well specified that this is just really summed up. The question is how can I return a value when undefined is returned? Meanwhile I've edited it so the forEach doesn't confuse people.

Comment: you have to use try/catch because series[i] when i > series.length is going to throw an exception.

Comment: @GastónCorti no it won't throw any error, it will just be undefined. `var x = []; x[1000] // undefined`

Answer (score 0):

If you have sorted `n`, you could filter `series` by checking the index in `n`.

If only `data` is needed, you could map this property.

```js
var n = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22],
    series = [{ data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [10] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] } ],
    result = series.filter((_, i) => n.includes(i));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check like this -

```
var x = i < series.length ? series[i].data : null;
```

Check this [JS bin](https://jsbin.com/famolebiwu/1/edit?js,console) to play around

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var n = [1,2,3,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,20,21,22];
n.forEach((i) => {
var series = [{data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},
          {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}, {data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []},{data: []}, {data: []},
          {data: [10]},{data: []},{data: []},{data: []},{data: [10]},{data: []}, {data: []}, {data: []}]
          var inArray = i < series.length;
          var x = inArray ? series[i].data : "out of bounds";
          console.log(x)
        });
```